# SQL-Statement for "exists row with specific values A and B or no row with value A at all"

Tags: mysql, sql

I came accross a problem creating an (MY)sql statement for a changed feature in my application. It is about implementing a permission model.

Right now the tables look like this

- photo (id : int, location : varchar)
- album (id: int, name : varchar)
- album2photo (album : int, photo : int)
- album2permission (album : int, who : varchar)

So basically photos belong to albums and permissions are album-based. An sql statement for getting all photos user stefan has access to would look like this:

```
SELECT photo.* FROM photo
JOIN album2photo ON album2photo.photo=photo.id
JOIN album2permission ON album2permission.album=album2photo.album
WHERE album2permission.who IN ('stefan')
```

Now I want to achieve an additional kind of restriction. I want to block users from seeing specific photos in an album. For doing so I thought about creating another table

- photo2permission (photo, who)

How it works now is that a user has access to all photos of an album except those for which there are specific photo permissions and he does not belong to those users permitted for the photo. Let me give you an example:

There is an album (1) with photos (10, 11, 12), the permissions look like this:

- album2permission: (1, stefan) ; (1, katrin)
- photo2permission: (11, katrin)

So stefan and katrin should be able to see the following photos:

- stefan: 10, 12
- katrin: 10, 11, 12

Both are allowed to see the photos of album 1 because for both there is an entry in album2permission, but stefan is blocked from seeing photo 11 because for that photo there are specific permissions and stefan does not belong to the list of users permitted for that photo.

My problem now is the corresponding sql statement, especially the condition "there are no restrictions for the photo OR person does belong to permitted users". Something that would work obviously is:

```
SELECT photo.* FROM photo
JOIN album2photo ON album2photo.photo=photo.id
JOIN album2permission ON album2permission.album=album2photo.album
WHERE album2permission.who IN ('stefan')
AND (
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM photo2permission WHERE photo2permission.photo=photo.id)
OR 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM photo2permissionWHERE photo2permission.photo=photo.id AND photo2permission.who='stefan')
)
```

But this strikes me as very inelegant and inefficient. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful comments. At first I was wondering if the information I gave was maybe even too detailed. Turns out, it was not. In fact dan1111 pointed out exactly the two problems which caused me headaches when deciding between the model I described above (not sure whether to call it whitelist or not because empty list means all are allowed) and the one with a blacklist.

Comment: As you both noted more background information might help. The application in question is a personal project of mine. It is essentially an web application that stores all my personal photos and is also reachable via internet for family members and friends. So I myself am allowed to see all photos and am some kind of omnipotent admin. Other users are only able to see those albums I granted them access to. While I am not very restrictive in what albums people are allowed to see, I want to make sure that certain photos are only visible to a selected group of people.

Comment: An example might be as follows: I am recently dating and went on a couple of excursions with my date. As the relationship is quite new, I did not tell my family and some of my friends of the girl yet. So while I want my family and friends to see those photos from the excursions that contain not my date, I want to make sure that photos with my date are only accessible by me and the date.
That is why I decided for the model above because this enables me to add new user accounts to the application later without having to update the blacklists.

Comment: Now concerning the two problems dan1111 pointed out: As I myself am allowed to see all  the photos, in the case that I do not want anybody except of me to see a photo, I just add myself to photo2permission. For the other issue I am planning on implementing a background job which automatically adds me to each photo someone else was allowed to see it. Because as you already stated, it might turn out that I will delete the date's account. And then everybody else would be able to see those photos.

Comment: As you both brought so much to the discussion it is a little bit difficult to decide which answer to take. For my use case I will stick with the solution Aqapwlesu wrote. But as dan1111 pointed out a couple of flaws that I could easily have overlooked by focussing on my data design, I will accept his answer. I hope that is okay for you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is your data design, which inherently requires a convoluted query to check.**  And this design has other problems, too:

1. **The permission setting for one user should be determined by looking *only* at records for that user.**  Within this design, it's necessary to check all other users' records to determine a user's permission.  And adding or changing a user might affect other users.  In your example above, what if you wanted to delete the user Katrin from your database?  Deleting all the records of Katrin would suddenly alter the permissions of Stefan.  Now they would have access to photo 11.
2. **There is no way to express the idea that no users can access a certain photo.**  This seems like a significant issue.

**I would solve this by changing the data design.**

There are various options, but perhaps the simplest option within what you have already done would be to make `photo2permission` be *negative*. In other words, an entry here would mean the user is *blocked* from seeing a photo.

Then your query would be this (I have renamed it to *blockedphotos* for clarity):

```
SELECT photo.* FROM photo
JOIN album2photo ON album2photo.photo=photo.id
JOIN album2permission ON album2permission.album=album2photo.album
WHERE album2permission.who IN ('stefan')
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM blockedphotos WHERE 
      blockedphotos.photo=photo.id and 
      blockedphotos.who='stefan'
)
```

A left join would be a further option, in many cases more efficient:

```
SELECT photo.* FROM photo
JOIN album2photo ON album2photo.photo=photo.id
JOIN album2permission ON album2permission.album=album2photo.album
LEFT JOIN blockedphotos ON
      blockedphotos.photo=photo.id and 
      blockedphotos.who='stefan'
WHERE album2permission.who IN ('stefan')
AND blockedphotos.photo is null
```

Comment: This is not correct.  Having positively specified permissions is totally fine and the sql does not need to be convoluted - see my answer.  If you go to having to actually block all users who do not have permissions to a photo, that will become very inefficient for the user (you have 200 users and you only want to grant to a single user, so user has to deny to 199 instead of grant to one), or the software (would have to do the same if you don't make the user do it) and to the database (199 blockedphotos records vs. one granted record).

Comment: @AgapwIesu your response doesn't address the specific flaws I pointed out with the OP's permission system.  The system as currently designed is problematic.  The negative permission system is only one possible alternative, and whether it is efficient or not depends on the typical use.  (If most users get access to entire albums, with access to specific photos only occasionally blocked, it will be efficient).

Comment: Hmmm... I think you are right... so, would you edit your answer to use a join instead of the subquery?  A join would be more efficient, and editing your answer would allow me to remove my downvote.  Sorry for jumping the gun.  I should have thought through your answer more carefully.

Comment: I removed the downvote.  Again, my apologies - bad morning.  Still, as I think more through your answer, I think that while correct, it assumes the model is one of blocking access.  With a minor change (adding a photoisprivate boolean), a grant-access model would work fine and address the problems you point out.  Wouldn't it?  And then it would depend on whether it is more likely that the user would be giving access to a few other users while denying the rest, or blocking a few users and allowing the rest.

Comment: @AgapwIesu the question seems to imply a model of blocking access here.  But really we know very little about the requirements and therefore can only speculate about the correct design.  I merely suggested one option, mainly because the changes required would be small. Your idea might be a better design, but I don't think we have enough information to know.

Comment: You are right about that too - the implication of blocking access is definitely there.  It's even a bit more than just implied.  I don't think my model is better.  I think it just depends on which they are trying to accomplish.  I agree we don't have enough information, but if I had to guess, from that implication, I'd say that the model you suggest is the better one.

Comment: Also, thanks for catching the downsides of his model.  I have learned a couple of things from this discussion with you.  I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

this will do it:

```
SELECT photo.* FROM photo
JOIN album2photo ON album2photo.photo=photo.id
JOIN album2permission ON album2permission.album=album2photo.album
LEFT JOIN photo2permission ON photo.id = photo2permission.photo
WHERE album2permission.who IN ('stefan') AND
      (photo2permission.who = 'stefan' or photo2permission.who is null)
```

the LEFT join makes it so that when the photo has corresponding records in photo2permissions, you actually get values in the fields for that table, but if the photo has no permissions, then you get nulls.  So you filter on either condition - either the permission is there, with 'stefan' specifically included, or there are no values in that table at all for this photo.

But, as Dan1111 has pointed out in his answer, your data model will cause the deletion of a user to potentially grant access to other users.  You will need to either be careful to deal with that case, or change your model.  One option is to add a photoisprivate boolean to the photo table, which would get marked true whenever users have to have specific rights to view that photo.  Then the condition would change to...

```
WHERE album2permission.who IN ('stefan') AND
      (photo.photoisprivate = false OR photo2permission.who = 'stefan')
```

The deciding factor for whether you do this, or the blockedphotos model DAN suggests, I think, is whether you are more likely to have a situation where you grant permission to one user (or a few), leaving out the rest, or whether you want to block one or a few users, while allowing the rest to have access.  Are you having the users grant access or block access?  Your model should reflect the answer to that question.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f715/3

Comment: By the way, why say IN ('stefan') instead of = 'stefan'?

Comment: The IN clause was left from simplifying the permission model a bit. In fact there are not only users but also groups (I call them profile), that can contain users but no additional groups. So the condition in the statement looks more like album2permission.who IN ('user:stefan', 'profile:Family') . Nevertheless if I am not mistaken your solution will work for that case as well. I just have to do it like this: photo2permission.who IS NULL OR photo2permission.who IN ('user:stefan', 'profile:Family')